# Blender 2.92 Cannot import OBJ and linked MTL File correctly

Tags: import, obj

OBJ Import ignores MTL File therefore not importing Textures at all. I have tested with several Assets from different Platform as well as my own export. All are imported blank. I followed the instructions from other post, but no difference. Checked the OBJ and MTL File internally, nothing suspicious. Are many Assets just broken, Blender having a bug or I am missing something? Is there an example where the import together with a MTL File is working?

MTL File:

```
# Blender MTL File: 'Moon рабочий.blend'
# Material Count: 1

newmtl Moon
Ns 96.078431
Ka 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000
Kd 0.640000 0.640000 0.640000
Ks 0.500000 0.500000 0.500000
Ke 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
Ni 1.000000
d 1.000000
illum 2
```

Comment: Exporting and reimporting works for me. What's the `map_Kd` line in the .mtl?

Comment: There's not a texture referenced in the MTL you posted. So it's not surprising it imports without one.

Comment: You are right. I have just made a new export and made sure that the texture of the asset is saved before exporting to OBJ. then the MTL file contains a "map_Kd" which was missing before. That was the headache. THX!

Answer (score 0):

Solution: MTL File must contain map_Kd. And of course, the Path to the Texture must be correct.
Then Opening the OBJ in any 3D Viewer should load its Texture as well.

Tested in Blender 2.92 using Export/Import.

Thx [scurest](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/211683/blender-2-92-cannot-import-obj-and-linked-mtl-file-correctly#comment357224_211683)